VSCode SFDX Deploy Source to Org -- Seems to be attempting to validate against multiple environments?
I have a LWC which is currently being used in an Experience Cloud site.
I have VSCode authenticated with a sandbox org, and I attempted to make one change (removing a particular design attribute from the LWC) and then deploy the changed LWC back to the sandbox org, using the SFDX Deploy Source to Org command.
However, I'm getting this error:

lwc/portal_Navigation/portal_Navigation.js-meta.xml: You can't remove the property tag(s) named 'logoNavigationLink' specified in targetConfig lightningCommunity__Default. This component is found in 2 Development Instance(s) and 1 Published Instance(s). Use the following component paths to locate the component:
[Development] ascend Portal > ascend Portal Site Template (Theme) > Portal_Custom_Login_Theme (Widget) > navigation (Panel) > portal_Navigation (LWC)
[Published] ascend Portal > ascend Portal Site Template (Theme) > Portal_Custom_Login_Theme (Widget) > navigation (Panel) > portal_Navigation (LWC)

In the sandbox in the UI, I opened up the site in Experience Builder and removed the component I'm attempting to make changes to from my site pages, and then republished the site.
When I re-tried sfdx Deploy Source to Org, I got the exact same error message, except that it changed from "2" to "1" Development instances.
So, I'm starting to suspect that VSCode is validating my deployment against not only the current sandbox that I'm authenticated in, but also another sandbox and the Production org. Am I crazy or is that what's happening here? How do I tell VSCode to ONLY deploy this change to the sandbox org I have set as default?
